# $(this).attr() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing a script that will allow my classmates to upload a picture and I'm using this code:

```
var SomeVar = this.class //or similar like this.attr('class')
$('body').attr('style', 'background-image:' + SomeVar)
```

However, when I'm testing this code:

```
function Prueba() {
    var hola = this.class
    alert(hola)
}
```

it alerts `undefined`.

You can see the webpage at [8a13.zzl.org](http://8a13.zzl.org).

Comment: How and where are you calling `Prueba()`? This information will define the value of the `this` variable.

Comment: i think `this` is `window` in your context

Comment: with an onclick in a li

Comment: Whose `class` are you trying to get??

Answer (score 2):

Use `className`:

```
function Prueba() {
    var hola = this.className;
    alert(hola)
}
```

This should work if Prueba is an event handler (if it's not inline).

---

But depending on what you're trying to do, you'll probably want to use a jQuery function such as `hasClass`:

```
if($('something').hasClass('someclass')) { // ...
```

---

Note: you should name your function `prueba`, uppercase initials are reserved for constructor functions by convention.

Answer (score 0):

You set "style" attribute so you probably will want to read it either:

```
var hola = $('body').attr('style');
```

Or try to rephrase your question as it is not clear what do you want.

Comment: I want to use $(this) in mi test

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not in the context of event / element.
We generally use this for specific html element.
In this case you are calling a function. so it may not work.

```
$("yourelement").click(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
}
```

In above example it will work.